# ExtJS - Where should I put new proxy file?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a new proxy for a ExtJS 6.2.1 application:

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.proxy.MyProxy', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.proxy.Proxy',
    // ...
});
```

Where would be the best way to put this class in my app directory structure?
Would just creating a new `proxy` dir and putting it inside be OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ExtJS convention, it is advised to start your class names with something that is not `Ext`, rather `MyApp` or something like that, so that you can tell which class belongs to ExtJS framework. And the last part in the class name should specify the class you are creating, which is also the name of the `.js` file that contains the definition.

So create a file called `MyProxy.js`, and define your class like:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.data.proxy.MyProxy', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.proxy.Proxy',
    // ...
});
```

In ExtJS `Ext.data.proxy.Proxy` is defined in a `Proxy.js` file in `ext/data/proxy` folder. So I would recommend mirroring this structure, and if your application resides in `app` folder (as with default settings), the full path of your own proxy class definition would be:

```
/app/data/proxy/MyProxy.js
```